# How to easily grant Samba user permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

I created a share on my Raspberry PI pointing to `/var/www/html` folder so I can easily upload files to my website.

After setting it up my username (Arges86) had only read access even though it was set in `smb.conf` file as writeable:

```
[Website]
    writeable = yes
    path = //var/www/html
    valid users = Arges86
```

After much googling, I found that since the folder was created by root, it had access. So I changed the folder permissions with:

```
chown -R Arges86 //var/www/html
```

If I want to change the folder permission later on (through Webmin or some other means) do I have to `chown` the folder again manually?

Or is there a better way of adjusting its permissions?

Comment: This sentence: "*If I want to change the folder permission later*" is unclear. If you want to change to what state? You should probably use group membership, but first you need to specify your question.

Comment: *so I can easily upload files to my website*, but so can everybody else, though. You have just circumvented one of the most basic security features of Web sites.

Comment: techraf, If I want to (through Webmin) add/remove permissions to the folder, cab I just adjust permissions through the GUI, or do I have to manually use chown in the terminal again?

Comment: MariusMatutiae,  by giving 'Arges86' ownership (which has a password associated with it)  of the folder, how did I leave myself vulnerable? My understanding of Samba is that it's only accessible in my network. Just like any other shared drive.